# Обособление несогласованных определений

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, необходимо ли ставить запятые в предложении **"этот человек (,) с добрыми, умными глазами (,) вертелся как белка в колесе"?** Если да, то эта постановка знака препинания рассматривается с точки зрения находящегося в препозиции дополнительного определения, выраженного указательным местоимением "этот"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинальном тексте Чехова нет обособления:

*Буркин и Иван Иваныч вышли на балкон; отсюда был прекрасный вид на сад и на плес, который теперь на солнце блестел, как зеркало. Они любовались и в то же время жалели, что **этот человек с добрыми, умными глазами, который рассказывал им с таким чистосердечием**, в самом деле вертелся здесь, в этом громадном имении, как белка в колесе, а не занимался наукой или чем-нибудь другим, что делало бы его жизнь более приятной.*.. https://ilibrary.ru/text/461/p.1/index.html

Местоимение ***этот*** необходимо по содержанию текста, обособление  оборота не связано с ним.

Человек — существительное с неопределенным значением, оно может иметь при себе два необособленных определения: согласованное определение ***этот*** в препозиции и несогласованное определение ***с добрыми, умными глазами*** в постпозиции.

Отсутствие обособления, вероятно,  связано с наличием **однородных определений** (*с добрыми, умными*) и с общей **структурой** предложения. В других условиях обособление несогласованного определения было бы возможным, например:

*Они  жалели, что  этот человек,  **с добрыми и умными глазами,  чистосердечный и простой,** вертелся здесь, как белка в колесе, а не занимался наукой или чем-нибудь другим, более интересным.*

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, необособленное определение "с добрыми, умными глазами" будет выполнять роль подлежащего вместе с существительным с неопределенным значением?

Comment: Нет, человек - это вполне самодостаточное слово, оно является подлежащим.  Для сравнения: роль подлежащего могут выполнять такие словосочетания:что-то новое, что-нибудь другое,  нечто невообразимое (примеры из Синтаксиса современного русского языка).